# Why do named imports cause slower builds and larger output?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was looking at the [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage) documentation and saw the below comment about how to properly do an import in ES6.

What is the technical reason that doing a named import is slower and causes larger output?

```
Notice that in the above example, we used:

import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

instead of

import {RaisedButton} from 'material-ui';

This will make your build process faster and your build output smaller. For a complete mapping of Material-UI components to import, see /index.js inside the Material-UI npm package root directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly enough context to see what's happening.
There are two separate things going on.

1. Default exports are typically going to be bigger than property exports.

   ```
   export default ObjectWithAllKindsOfStuff {}
   export function someFunction () { }
   ```

   The second one is going to be smaller, practically 100% of the time, if they're in the same file.
2. Importing a single function from `@angular/core` is going to require opening a whole lot more files (taking longer) than importing everything from `@angular/a/b/c/d/e/f.js`.
   If you are in the root folder's `index.js`, and you `export * from './a'`, and in there, you `export * from './b'`, et cetera...  then for WebPack or Rollup or whatever, it has to load all of the files below, to figure out what each one exports, so it can tell where the function actually lives.

Their example is actually unfair, in that using the `import { x } from 'package/SubPackage/SubSubPackage';` is going to be even smaller than `import All from 'package/SubPackage/SubSubPackage';`, but if you `import { x } from 'pacakge';` and it has to go all the way through every folder, spidering through all of the exports, to figure out which file the function comes from, that's the comparison they're really making - it has nothing to do with the `export {property} from` versus `export Namespace from` if they're both talking about the same file, in the same subfolder.

Comment: _"Default exports are typically going to be bigger than property export"_ Why should they be bigger? _"Their example is actually unfair"_ Two methods, one is faster. Fairness is not a concept that can be applied here.

Comment: Why should they be bigger? Because tree-shaking, based upon statically declared exports, versus dynamic members of a JS object. That’s why. And they’re making claims that full exports are better than partial. All they’ve done is said “we’re doing things our way, and are hiding the actual reasonings, and we’re going to tell you that our way is faster, even though there’s an even faster way we’re not telling you about”. I’m not talking about “fair” in some honesty + feelings sense, I’m talking fair in terms of mathematical accuracy of claims.

Comment: Otherwise, I could just say that my method of attaching everything to the global scope is thousands of times faster than either method, and they can stop arguing. Either you’re going to be accurate, or you’re going to spin things in your own direction... They both have pros and cons, and should be explained as such.

Comment: The method they are championing as faster is actually slower. Note that I said “method”, not folder. If you consider the folder to be part of the method, then there are actually four methods, and they’re ignoring the fastest and smallest one. To what end?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I get the impression that you assume that a default export represents the whole module. It certainly can be used that way, but that's not the the point of a default export.

Comment: You’re wrong. I assume that a default export is am object, which in the CommonJS realm is the `default` property of a module.exports object, within an ES5-friendly module system, and represents a typical CommonJS exports object (that being a standard JS value of some form, be it a scalar or complex value). I also assume that declared ES6 exports can be statically analysed  and as such, the code which those functions contain cam be statically analysed, and as such if that file imports 8 other files, but based on the entry point in the dependency graph (of whatever "app.js" / etc you have)...

Comment: If none of the statically exported functions which your app is importing directly access any of the code in the other files, then those other files don’t even need to be loaded, for the sake of generating that particular build. This, vastly reducing the build size, versus loading the default (which can not be statically analysed, and thus all imported files, and all code within, are loaded). If you haven’t yet, look into RollupJS

Comment: What I’m saying is that: `import Library from 'library';` post tree-shaking will be the slowest and the largest bundle, and `import { specificMethod } from 'library/subcomponent';` will be the smallest. But they’re selling `import SubComponent from 'library/subcomponent';` as the fastest and smallest, which is untrue, due to the ability to utilise tree-shaking using the other means.

Comment: _"I assume that a default export is am object"_ It is whatever you export. Semantics aside there's nothing special about default exports. You (probably) don't need tree-shaking with `import SubComponent from 'library/subcomponent'` because you only include a part of the library in the first place, as opposed to `import {SubComponent} from 'library'`. That's the whole point of doing it.

Comment: So you missed the part where I said that in CommonJS, module.exports is anything you want to make it? You do need tree-shaking; do you know how large the Angular 2 library is? The difference matters. And you can *always* make it smaller by using `import { method } from 'library/subcomponent';` instead of `import SubComponent from 'library/subcomponent';` Which I believe I said above. Smaller and faster than what was being advertised as smallest and fastest.

Comment: `import { method }` - This is what the whole discussion is about. You simply assume that this is possible. A component is atomic. There are no parts that you can import individually. Moreover if you import a "method" it's no longer a method. _"You do need tree-shaking"_ - Again: If I explicitly import only a function from a huge library, and that function is defined in a separate file, which I reference with the import, then I don't need tree-shaking because only that file gets included in the first place. Your answer revolves around a very specific situation.

Comment: Actually, my answer revolves around *the most general case* as the example code in the article uses *all kinds of libraries, like React, to illustrate its point*, and the OP asks why importing everything is smaller and faster than importing a static thing. It’s not. The article doesn’t provide disambiguation. I have. And you’re now griping about the fact that I have? In the most general way possible, given that ES6 imports apply to npm/yarn just as well as they apply to hand-written code. Your case of a component is not the general case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125593/discussion-between-zeroflagl-and-norguard).

Comment: Code is the general case. And I am using `method` because `function` is a reserved keyword, but if you really want to be that pedantic (...and yet not, otherwise you would have realised that my position is correct, and is guaranteed to be at *worst* equally large) then `import { someFunction } from '@namespace/product/subproduct/furthersegregation';` is going to be at worse equivalent to `import SegregatedPublicAPI from '@namespace/product/subproduct/furthersegregation';`. This is never not the case, and yet, the article sells it otherwise, if you aren’t paying attention to the caveats...

Comment: ...the caveats attached to the superlatives... Which weren’t paid attention to, hence the question on SO in the first place.